# Unzip csv from url that doesn’t contain filename results in “File is not a zip file.”

Tags: python, python-requests, zip, bytesio

I want to download a bunch of zipped CSVs. Ideally I want to extract each zipped csv and process it with pandas without having to save the files to disk. 
The issue I am having is that the URLs I need to get the zip files from don't contain filename.zip in them but look as follows:

https://api.awrcloud.com/v2/get.php?action=get_visibility&token=mytoken&project=client5Bw%5D&fileName=visibility_api-client-file+%5Bw%5D_2019-09-25-2019-10-23

What is weird is that sometimes when processing all my urls  I am able to process the file with the function below and unzip the csv. But most of the time I get the error: *File is not a zip file*.

The thing is that if I copy paste the URL into my browser I am able to download the file.  I read and implemented many of the related topics here on stackoverflow related to unzipping in memory but none of them have helped so far.

```
from dotenv import dotenv_values
import requests
import pandas as pd
import zipfile
from io import BytesIO

def processRankingdata(url):

    response = requests.get(url)
    # {"response_code":25,"message":"Export in progress. Please come back later"}
    if "response_code" not in response:
        try:
            with zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response.content)) as thezip:
                for zipinfo in thezip.infolist():
                    with thezip.open(zipinfo) as thefile:
                       # yield zipinfo.filename, thefile
                        df = pd.read_csv(thefile)
        except Exception as e:
            print ('No Zip file for ' + url)
            #print (e)
            with open('awr_no_zip_failed_urls.txt', 'a+') as filehandle:
                filehandle.write(url + '\n')
        else:
```

The response headers when accessing the URL from the browser are as follow:

```
cache-control: private, no-cache, no-store, proxy-revalidate, no-transform
content-description: File Transfer
content-disposition: attachment; filename=client-name-ranking-export-2019-09-25-2019-10-23_csv.zip
content-length: 148893
content-type: application/download
date: Wed, 23 Oct 2019 14:07:18 GMT
pragma: no-cache
server: Apache/2.4.37 (Amazon) PHP/7.0.32
status: 200
vary: User-Agent
x-powered-by: PHP/7.0.32
```

Thanks for your patience and support.

Comment: pandas can read `.csv.zip` from url `pandas.read_csv("http://....csv.zip", compression='zip')`

Comment: if you use own method then you should first check what you get in `reponse.content`. Maybe there is some useful message about problem. Sometimes server can be too busy to send data to all users and you can get wrong data. And then you should try again.

Comment: This is what I get at that URL: `{"response_code":11,"message":"Failed - invalid token"}`

Comment: @furas thank you for your contribution. I am aware that panads can read zips but in my case it doesn't seem to work as the URL doesn't directly contain filename.zip.

Comment: @FiddleStix  yes I am aware, that the url I posted doesn't resolve to a zip. This is due to the fact that I redacted the API-Token as I would like to keep that private.